# Openlayers waits for base layer until loading other layers, is paralleled loading possible?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am loading a base layer from OSM and a WMS layer from my local geoserver using the latest stable openlayers (2.13.1).

Performance is okay, but openlayers seems to wait for the base layer to load before loading anything from my WMS layer and sometimes the OSM layer is performing slower than I would like. I was wondering is there a way to get openlayers to load the WMS layer first or even both in parallel?

Also, I have been using openlayers 3 and the performance is much better, perhaps as it seems to load both layers at once.

Comment: Is your WMS defined in the same projection/coordinate system as the OSM basemap layer?

Comment: The osm baselayer is in EPSG:900913 and my wms is in EPSG:4326. I've loaded the OpenLayers.Map object with projection: "EPSG:900913" and when I add the wms layer the transformation seems to have happened automatically.